# Program Arduino Mega Adk on linux

Tags: linux

for a project my supervisor gave me a Arduino Mega ADK board (https://store.arduino.cc/arduino-mega-adk-rev3) and the usb-cable.

I only programmed a Atmega32 8 bit controller on linux ubuntu. I have no possibility to use windows (i heard it's easy to program the arduino using atmel studio). I can only use ubuntu 16.04. Is there a convient way to program the Arduino like a microcontroller?

I'm not aloud to use the highlevel Arduino libraries. I have to do a cascaded control for a dc-motor and sensor-fusion.

Thanks in advance.

If it's offtopic, could you transfer me to a suitable board?

Comment: You can still use the Arduino bootloader even if you don't use the Arduino libraries and development flow.  Easiest approach is to install the Arduino IDE, put it in verbose mode, use it once, and copy out the avrdude command line it generates, then adapt that to your own project.  You can use their avr-gcc install, too.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Eclipse](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/helios/m7/eclipse-ide-linux-developers), along with [AVR-GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/avr-gcc) and [AVRDude](https://www.nongnu.org/avrdude/) and an [AVR plug-in for Eclipse](http://avr-eclipse.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Plugin_Download). Debugging may be a little painful since you don't have all the tools that Atmel Studio gives you. I'd question your employer if you aren't allowed to use the best (free) tools even if they do run on Windows.

Really all you need is the avr-gcc and avrdude to write software for it, you can use any text editor (although it isn't really convienent).  Seems like they are pigeon-holing you into a difficult job. Good luck.

Comment: the thing is that unfortunately no windows computer is available

Comment: i can use the atmega libraries i think

Comment: Eclipse runs on Linux Ubuntu, as well as all the other tools I linked to...

Comment: yes i know, i just explained the the supervisors behaviour. Thank you, i'll take a look at it :)